# Javascript image path replace not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const {path, originalname} = req.files[i]
    
   
console.log(originalname)
const parts = originalname.split('.')
const ext = parts[parts.length - 1]
const newPath = path+ '.' + ext
console.log(path)
   

fs.renameSync(path, newPath)
uploadedFiles.push(newPath.replace('uploads/', '') )
console.log(newPath) //http://localhost:4000/uploads/uploads/6ddf3214a3741298f1e8c11650a72b48.jpg
```

I am trying to replace the second `uploads/` with an empty string by using `newPath.replace` and when I try to `console.log` the result, it still does not replace the string. Can anyone find out what is the problem why the string could not be replaced?

I expect the string should be replaced while following the documentation but I tried to print out the result that it does not replace the string.

Comment: `replace` does not mutate the string itself, you have to reassign it to the new value: `newPath = newPath.replace('uploads/', '')`. Also, if you need to replace multiple occurrences, use a regex or [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) instead.

Comment: `replaceAll` is a good alternative but a fairly recent addition (ES2021), so depending on the project or client, you'd need to polyfill. Regular `.replace()` with regex will have broader compatibility, as long as you pass the `g` flag.